# Checking if SOAP has been installed on a CentOS with Directadmin

Tags: centos, php, installation, soap

How should I check that and how should I install it?

I don't think `phpinfo()` can help, is that true?

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP is a php extension, so if it's correctly installed it will appear in `phpinfo()`.  It looks like with DirectAdmin they have some custom scripts to rebuild apache/php.  You would need to use those, and add `--enable-soap` to the PHP configure line.

Answer (score 4):

To check if SOAP is available you can use the following shell command:

```
 php -i | grep soap
```